# jQuery add a class based on the current class

Tags: jquery, class

I have got this script

```
var dot = $('<i class="fa fa-circle"/>'),
    addDot = $(".rating li").slice(2).prepend(dot);

var excelent = $(".rating li").hasClass("standard").addClass("good");
```

It should:

1) Add to each li (after second li) object dot - it works just right now.

2) Based on the current class asign new class to this li

For example last li should had .good class.

I have pasted whole script here http://codepen.io/marciapn/pen/medzwN

Comment: Console error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hasClass(...).addClass is not a function`

Comment: `.hasClass()` returns `True/False`. You're best to use the answer below, which is the best way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) does not return a jQuery object with which you can call additional jQuery methods. Rather, it returns a **boolean**.

However, you can include the condition implicitly in the selector itself like

```
var excelent = $(".rating li.standard").addClass("good");
```

The statement above will only add the `good` class to those elements with the `standard` class because those are the only elements that will be selected in the first place.

```js
var dot = $('<i class="fa fa-circle"/>'),
  addDot = $(".rating li").slice(2).prepend(dot);

var excelent = $(".rating li.standard").addClass("good");
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #3F434E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 600;
  list-style: none;
}
.price {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
.good {
  color: #84e07c;
}
.bad {
  color: #e07ccd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="rating">
  <li>History</li>
  <li>Overdue <span class="price">Sum</span>
  </li>
  <li class="extension">1 <span class="price">5000 CZK</span>
  </li>
  <li class="extension">2 <span class="price">5000 CZK</span>
  </li>
  <li class="schedule">+45 <span class="price">5000 CZK</span>
  </li>
  <li class="incaso">+454 <span class="price">5000 CZK</span>
  </li>
  <li class="standard">-1 <span class="price">5000 CZK</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```